# WP not logging in at first time

Tags: users, redirect, wp-login-form, cookies, bug

I've been experiencing a weird "bug" in my website which I have a form in the front page to do the log in, it doesn't log, redirects me to the WP-login.php and it says the Cookies may not be active in my browser.

I've checked my browser and the cookies are active.

After log in (on the WP-login page) it never happens again. But after cleaning my cache and testing again, it does the problem.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this happen with all plugins disabled and with a default theme?

Comment: yes, still equal.

Comment: Does the server do any caching?

Comment: Nope, I think it doesn't cache.

Comment: Can you try to change the salts in wp_config.php? You may want to also try to reinstall the WordPress core files just in case something may be corrupted.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I've checked everything. Also updated my WP instance to the newer one aswell and the problem still remains.

Comment: Hello! For everyone who is having a issue with this aswell I've found the problem and it's now fixed, thanks for everyone for the help aswell. I'll leave the solution here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cookie-error-when-logging-in
Check Mirajas comment for the solution :)

Comment: This used to happen to me. It was related to an issue with the URL in the Wordpress settings. Logging in the first time would create a cookie, but the login form would redirect to the proper site URL. What version of Wordpress are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I too experience this when I go to the [domain]/wp-admin page to login.

The issue seems to be with the redirect which loops back to the login page instead of going to the Dashboard.

Instead of going to the [domain]/wp-admin to login, try going to [domain]/wp-login.php instead. The redirect seems to work correctly this way.

Best regards.